# How do I escape characters in YQL using Yahoo's Answer API?

Tags: escaping, yahoo, yql

I'm using Yahoo's Answer API via YQL. My query is "how to cook bacon" and I need to include the double quotes because this does an exact match, you can see the results differ in their web based search:

```
http://answers.yahoo.com/search/search_result;_ylt=Av2RD2lUBAad6J5WYYTma6gjzKIX;_ylv=3?p=%22how+to+cook+bacon%22
```

vs

```
http://answers.yahoo.com/search/search_result;_ylt=Av2RD2lUBAad6J5WYYTma6gjzKIX;_ylv=3?p=how+to+cook+bacon
```

The problem is I can't escape characters I tried `\"` and tried including `%22`. Was just wondering if there was another method that would work?

Here's my example query without quotes:

```
http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?_uiFocus=answers&q=select%20*%20from%20answers.search%20where%20query%3D%22cars%22%20and%20category_id%3D2115500137%20and%20type%3D%22resolved%22#h=select%20*%20from%20answers.search%20where%20query%3D%22how%20to%20cook%20bacon%22%20and%20type%3D%22resolved%22
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Josh's answer was on the right track to the original issue of quoting or escaping the Answers query as it passes through YQL. But, playing with this further, I think the real problem is trying to duplicate the Answers UI results through the Answers API (which in turn is read by YQL).

I am not able to match the same set of results from the [Answers API](http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/V1/questionSearch.html) compared to the [Answers website](http://answers.yahoo.com/). I think the difference is the rank sort order, but that doesn't seem to be available in the API.

As an alternative, you could use the Answers RSS feeds and process them through YQL:

1. Go to answers.yahoo.com and enter your sample search ["how to cook bacon"](http://answers.yahoo.com/search/search_result?p=%22how+to+cook+bacon%22&submit-go=Search+Y!+Answers).
2. On the results page, grab the RSS link on the left side nav ([example](http://answers.yahoo.com/rss/search?p=%22how+to+cook+bacon%22&orderby=rank))
3. Use the RSS link along with the YQL "feed" module: [`select * from feed where url='http://answers.yahoo.com/rss/search?p=%22how+to+cook+bacon%22&scope=all&fltr=_en&question_status=all&date_submitted=all&category=0&answer_count=any&orderby=rank'`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20feed%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fanswers.yahoo.com%2Frss%2Fsearch%3Fp%3D%2522how%2Bto%2Bcook%2Bbacon%2522%26scope%3Dall%26fltr%3D_en%26question_status%3Dall%26date_submitted%3Dall%26category%3D0%26answer_count%3Dany%26orderby%3Drank%27)

You should get results like the following first result, which seem to match the order shown in the UI:

```
<item>
  <title>Resolved Question: How to cook bacon?
  <link>http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070416221341AAkZArM
  <guid isPermaLink="true">http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070416221341AAkZArM
  <pubDate>Tue, 17 Apr 2007 5:13:41 GMT
  <description>
</item>
```

In these RSS results the amount of data is just a summary, but you could extract the question id, then use the [get question API method](http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/V1/getQuestion.html) to pull down all the details for each question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes for your YQL query and then put double quotes within your content and YQL will pass along the double quotes with the data to Answers. Like so:

```
select * from answers.search where query='"how to cook bacon"' and type='resolved'
```

yields the following request to [Answers](http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch?query=%22how%20to%20cook%20bacon%22&type=resolved&start=0&results=10).

Comment: The URL you posted is just using double quotes around the query as required by YQL. I tried single quotes but this doesn't work, the results are actually worse because yahoo doesn't see single quotes as creating and exact match. You can compare http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20answers.search%20where%20query%3D%22how%20to%20cook%20bacon%22%20and%20type%3D%22resolved%22 to http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20answers.search%20where%20query%3D%22'how%20to%20cook%20bacon'%22%20and%20type%3D%22resolved%22